# Qual a origem da expressão “Bater as botas”?

Tags: significado, etimologia, expressões, origem-histórica

Utilizamos essa expressão quando alguém vem a falecer.

Exemplo:

> Nosso vizinho bateu as botas enquanto dormia.

Mas fiquei a pensar no sentido disso, qual a origem dessa expressão?

Porque quando penso em bater botas imagino um soldado do exercito fazendo continência. Mas ele está vivo e não morto, alguém que tenha falecido não teria como bater com as botas, então porque dizemos que o morto é quem bate as botas?

Comment: Assim sem qualquer tipo de investigação, acho que sempre interpretei subconscientemente de duas possíveis maneiras **1-** Bater as botas no sentido de sacudir ou bater para limpar ou tirar o pó, como que já não as usa mais para arrumar definitivamente. **2-** Quando se morre caindo espalhafatosamente de forma exagerada para trás (*cartoonish overacting*) as pernas subiriam e depois desceriam outra vez fazendo os pés bater no chão no retorno.

Comment: Em Portugal dizemos "bater a bota", no singular.

Comment: @ANeves Por acaso acho que ouço com bastante frequência tanto o singular como o plural da expressão.

Comment: Tem alguma diferença de sentido sendo singular ou plural?

Comment: Não, @FleuquerLima .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O Coronel Aleu de Oliveira dá a seguinte explicação em [*Presença Militar na Língua Portuguesa*](https://www.google.pt/search?q=%22militar%20na%20presen%C3%A7a%20de%20um%20superior%22&num=50&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-j72zvtzOAhVHQBQKHf4gC-cQ_AUIDigB&biw=1242&bih=585) (1993), também citada [neste artigo do Ciberdúvidas:](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-a-origem-de-bater-a-bota-a-mata-cavalos-e-borra-botas/29148)

> À semelhança de quando um militar na presença de um superior dá um passo à retaguarda e dá a seguir meia volta, quando se vai a retirar, batendo com as botas no chão, o ir-se embora desta vida é conhecido como o bater a bota.

Eu nunca fui à tropa, mas encontrei a explicação daquilo a que o Coronel se refere [neste blog do Tenente Perdigão](http://tenenteperdigao.blogs.sapo.pt/5770.html). O militar para dar meia volta cerimonialmente, roda o pé direito na direção requerida e «o pé esquerdo vai assentar, **com batimento**, junto ao primeiro» (meu negrito em todas as citações). Podem ouvir e ver este batimento [neste vídeo do exército brasileiro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FeUGUahwPB8). Ao segundo 15 ouve-se o batimento dos pés esquerdos dos soldados ao voltarem à direita; ao segundo 35 vê-se e ouve-se o batimento do mesmo grupo ao fazer meia volta.

Agora a questão é como é que o Coronel Oliveira sabe que é esta a origem duma expressão que já vem do século XIX. No entanto a expressão é plausível por duas razões. Na meia volta militar é só o pé esquerdo que bate, e a expressão original parece ser ***bater a bota*** e não ***bater as botas***. No Google Books só encontrei *bater as botas* a partir de 1962 [(em *A Rua e o Mundo* de Fran Martins)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=SJctAAAAYAAJ&q=%22batia%20as%20botas%22&dq=%22batia%20as%20botas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTltr0t9zOAhWCbhQKHZPfChoQ6AEIkAEwDw), enquanto *bater a bota* já aparece nas obras dos autores brasileiros Machado de Assis (1839-1908), Lima Barreto (1881-1922), Raul Pompeia (1863-95) e Artur Azevedo (1855-1908). O exemplo mais antigo que encontrei (dos que consegui datar) é de 1877 em [*A Pele do Lobo* de Artur Azevedo:](http://www.literaturabrasileira.ufsc.br/documentos/?action=download&id=28268)

> Hei de ser promovido na primeira vaga que aparecer. O Cantidiano está por pouco a **bater a bota**. Verás se o lugar é ou não é meu!

Em Portugal a ocorrência mais antiga que encontrei é só de 1938, em [*Ocidente: Revista Portuguesa*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=5WkYAQAAIAAJ&q=%22bates%20a%20bota%22&dq=%22bates%20a%20bota%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj815COtNzOAhWBOhQKHZEhCO4Q6AEINDAC), o que sugere que a origem da expressão é brasileira.

A outra razão para a plausibilidade da origem da expressão na retirada do soldado da presença de um oficial, é que *bater a bota* também já foi usado, pelo menos no Pernambuco, simplesmente com o significado de ‘ir embora’, como atesta em 1935 a [Revista do Instituto Arqueológico, Histórico e Geográfico Pernambucano:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Wws0AQAAIAAJ&q=%22bateu%20a%20bota%22&dq=%22bateu%20a%20bota%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVqIvertzOAhXFORoKHVw6CxQQ6AEIxgIwKQ)

> **Bater a bota**; fugir, desaparecer, pôr-se ao fresco; morrer, “A rapazeada que folgava no bumba da Varzea deu tamanha vaia na Yáyá Prata, que envergonhada **bateu a bota** para o Recife”. ([revista] A Pimenta).

Encontrei uma explicação alternativa [neste site](http://historiadoriso.com.br/category/ditados-girias/page/6), segundo a qual a expressão se teria divulgado durante a [Guerra do Paraguai (1864-70)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerra_do_Paraguai) porque soldados feridos ao morrer «sacudiam espasmodicamente as pernas, batendo as botas uma na outra». Não são dadas quaisquer referências, e ficaríamos com cerca de uma década para de «batendo as botas uma na outra» se passar a «bater a bota» na obra de Artur Azevedo. Precisaríamos também de uma origem separada para o *bater a bota* no sentido pernambucano de ‘ir embora’.

Answer (score -1):

Bates as botas vem do velho oeste num duelo com armas quando um acerta o outro em cheio cai na e a bota bate.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências. Especialmente ao se discutir etimologia, em que inúmeras origens plausíveis (ou não) podem ser facilmente aventadas, obras de referência ou registro históricos são fundamentais.

Answer (score -2):

Penso que é pelo mesmo motivo por que chamamos o cemitério de "cidade dos pés juntos": os mortos são enterrados com os pés junto, com as botas encostando uma na outra. Mas etimologia é provavelmente o assunto onde vicejam mais palpites furados.